# How to change field names in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to insert the data from get method into my database.

i am doing to get array from get method:

```
$data = $this->license_m->array_from_get(array('request','device_id','site_id','product','software_version','platform_os','platform_model','platform','launch_date','expiry_date'));
```

Now In my database i have a filed called site_key, and here i have in the get array its site_id.

So when i insert into database it shows error for undefined field site_id.

Which should be site_key

if i do like this

```
$data = array('site_key' =>$this->input->get('site_id')  );
```

then in only inserts in site_key field and my other fields are not inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append all the values to the array

```
$data = array('site_key' => $this->input->get('site_id'), 'next_value' => $this->input->get('next_val'));
```